# Unable to use System.Numeric in Xamarin studio c#

Tags: c#, xamarin, biginteger, xamarin-studio

I am writing a console project which requires some very large numbers above the limit of all classes in c#. I have read of a biginteger class which can support this. Despite this my c# compiler does not recognise the use of System.Numeric which is required to use the biginteger class. I am aware of and able to implement a work around using arrays to store the digits but this would be messier and I was wondering if there was an easier way to use this class somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a **reference** to `System.Numerics` in your console project:

[image]

Then include:

```
using System.Numerics;
```

Usage:

```
var bInt = new BigInteger();
```

> How do I get to this window?

To access the project's references, double click on the "References" item within your Solution/Project sub-tree.

[image]

Ref:

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit of a nube, how do I get to this window

Comment: @Joz In your solution tree/explorer window/pad, double click on the "References" item within your project sub-tree.